# Mockito in spring boot does not mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have a simple test case for which I am using Mockito in spring boot application.

***userOperation.java***

```
...
@Autowired
Validator nameValidator;

private boolean userOperation(String name) {
    NameStats nameStats = nameValidator.validate(name);
    if (!nameStats.isSuccess()) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return true;
}
...
```

***Validator.java***

```
public NameStats validate(String name)
{
    NameStats nameStats = new NameStats();
    // code goes here
    return nameStats;
}
```

testCase.java

```
...
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ImportFileOperationTest {

    @Mock
    Validator nameValidator;

    @Mock
    NameStats nameStats;

    @InjectMocks
    UserOperation operation;

    @Test
    public void  ConnectorDelegate0Test() {
        Mockito.when(nameValidator.validate(any(String.class))).thenReturn(nameStats);
        Mockito.when(nameStats.isSuccess()).thenReturn(true);
        operation.userOperation(restConsumerRequest);
    }

}
...
```

***Error :***

For the above test case, I am getting NullPointerException.
While tracing I found out that below line of code in test returns the null value.

```
Mockito.when(nameValidator.validate(any(String.class))).thenReturn(nameStats);
```

Because of the null value, when it tries to call `nameStats.isSuccess()` it is throwing nullpointexception even I have mocked the response to this function as `true`.

Question : 
1. Am I mocking the response right way?
2. Why the mocking function returns the null object?

***Update :***

*testCase.java*

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ImportFileOperationTest {

    @MockBean
    Validator nameValidator;

    NameStats nameStats;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    UserOperation operation;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void  ConnectorDelegate0Test() {
        nameStats = new nameStats();
        Mockito.when(nameValidator.validate(any(String.class))).thenReturn(nameStats);
        Mockito.when(nameStats.isSuccess()).thenReturn(true);
        operation.userOperation(restConsumerRequest);
    }

}
```

I tried to create the object `nameStats` manually and expected `validate` function to return that object but still, it returns `null`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: Can you try by commenting out the MockitoAnnotations call in your setup? You shouldn't need to do anything at all, Spring does the work.

Comment: Also, since you `@InjectMocks`, there is no (obvious) need for `@MockBean`. Can you try and replace `@MockBean` with just `@Mock`?

Comment: Yeah, this really looks like you just throw in as many annotations as possible. Don't do that. You don't use something because you can, but because you have to. Before using such annotations you better research them to understand when to use what!

Comment: @Gimby I tried commenting that out but still did not work.

Comment: @Turing85 Thak you for the suggestion. I have updated the code as per your suggestion, but unfortunately, still the same error. Just a quick question, have I properly mocked the when(...).thenReturn(...) in my code?

Comment: `@MockBean` needs to be used. `@InjectMocks` won't work - you need to have Spring autowiring correctly configured.

Comment: 1. Use constructor injection. stop autowiring fields, you just don't need to do so. 2. don't use spring to test your class if you don't need to. 3. Manually init the class and provide your mocks to id. inject mocks is not a IoC/DI framework and has significant gotchas. If you do this you can just test your java class in a simple and understandable way. If you do need to mock a spring bean read up on `@MockBean'

Comment: If you want to mock, you should be using `RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)`, not `SpringRunner`.

Comment: @GhostCat my apologies if my code is not clean. I am trying mockito for the first time and stuck with this issue for a long time. I have tried all the possible things still getting NullPointException.

Comment: In your updated test code, the nameStats object being returned by the mocked validator is not a mocked object, so the mocked functionality is not taking effect.

Comment: You have to decide whether spring or mockito are driving your test. If spring is, then you need to use `@MockBean` and/or explicit `Mockito.initMocks` calls. If Mockito is, then you need use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or equivalent. The problems you are experiencing are cause by trying to mix the two approaches.

Answer (score 10):

The test shall be either Mockito-driven or Spring-driven. Spring-driven would have `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` class-level annotations and mocks would be declared with `@MockBean` or explicitly instantied with `Mockito.initMocks`. Mockito-driven test would have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and mocks would be declared with `@Mock` and/or injected with `@InjectMocks`. Note the injection does not help when the instance such as `NameStats` is instantied with `new` in within the method.

The shown test does not have to be `@SpringBootTest` and therefore it could be written as Mockito-driven test like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ImportFileOperationTest {

@Mock
Validator nameValidator;

@InjectMocks
UserOperation operation;

@Test
public void  connectorDelegateTest() {
    NameStats nameStats = new NameStats();
    nameStats.setStats(Stats.SUCCESS);
    Mockito.when(nameValidator.validate(any(String.class))).thenReturn(nameStats);

    operation.userOperation(restConsumerRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me, I was mixing spring and mockito annotations

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `@InjectMocks` for all class types and `@Mock` need to be used for all associated attributes inside that class.

Example :

```
 class Product {

 ProductDetails  productDetails;

 }

 class ProductDetails {

 }
```

Sample Test case for above class :

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductTest {

    @Mock
    ProductDetails productDetails;

    @InjectMocks
    Product product;

}
```

Comment: I finally understood where to use InjectMocks and Mock annotations. Just a suggestion, add/edit the InjectMocks code in the starting of class and then add the @Mock code.

Comment: Could u ellaborate more.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem after upgrade to Spring Boot 2.
The reason is explained here https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-

> Since Mockito 2.1.0, only allow non-null instance of , thus null is not anymore a valid value.

So mock returns null, or empty list, because calls were set with `anyString()`, and object passed was null. To match value or null, use matcher `any()`.

Comment: saved a lot of time for me. Thanks!